# run the python code during a specific time without using cron job

Tags: python

I want to run my code for example, everyday one time between 2pm to 3pm which send out an email. I dont want to use cron job for this. Is there a way in python to achieve this?

my code is below

```
me=abc@gmail.com
you=bba@gmail.com
msg= MIMEMultipart('alternative') 
msg['subject'] = "test email"
msg['from'] = me
msg['to'] = you
text= "happy birthday"
html = '''\
        <html>
          <body> 
             <p>   hi,</p>
              <p> it's your  birthday</p>
            </body></html>
       '''


part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')      
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')      
msg.attach(part1)      
msg.attach(part2)      
s= smtplib.SMTP("hostname", port=1234)      
s.sendemail(me, you, msg.as_string())      
s.quit()
```

Comment: You code has several syntax errors, mainly missing quotation marks. Please fix them!

Answer (score 0):

Use time package of python.

```
import time

function fun():
    # Do something
white 1:
    fun()
    time.sleep(86400)
```

Start this from 2 PM to 3 PM once with `nohup python file.py`.

This script will stop once you shutdown your computer. You should restart the script once you restart the system at correct time.

You can also use the schedule package also.

```
import time
import schedule

function fun():
    # Do something

schedule.every().day.at("14:00").do(fun)

white 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Start this whenever you can. It will run at 2 PM only. If you restart the system you need to restart the script also.

To automate starting of this script whenever you restart your computer, you can use your bash_profile.

Use nano `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` whichever you have.
Add a line `nohup python/python3 file.py` in that and save.

PS: Use proper logging into a file.

**Edit: As per your requirement.**

```
from datetime import datetime

now_LOCAL = datetime.now()
function fun():
    # Do something

if(now_LOCAL.hour > 14 and now_LOCAL.hour <15):
    fun()
```

## you need to raise a flag so that it wont execute second time in between 2PM to 3PM

Comment: Thanks a lot for a really good idea. Actually, this a part of the program which uses cronjob to run once every 15 mins. so, i want it to send out an email for example between 2-3 pm. in this case, this solution might not work.

Comment: Ohh. You can do something like this then.
from datetime import datetime

now_LOCAL = datetime.now()
function fun():
    # Do something

if(now_LOCAL.hour > 14 and now_LOCAL.hour <15):
    fun()

Comment: This is going to run every 15 minutes with your cron. Every time you are going to check the time if it is in between 2PM and 3PM. If it is, do your work.